# mvc2 to mvc3 validation issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm extremely new to .NET and was given the task of upgrading an old application that we have so that it can run on a Windows 2012 server.  Right now, it is running on a 2003 server, but that will be going away soon, so...  This application was written using VS2003 and uses MVC2.  I was able to get it to the point where I can use VS2010, and I attempted to do an upgrade to MVC3 (I followed directions found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading)).  The code compiles and runs, but the problem is that the client side validation no longer works.

I've updated all the references to MVC3 in the web.config file, and I made sure to add :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

This is a large application with lots of views and lots of .ascx files, so moving to .cshtml is really not something that I want to do.

I realize I haven't given you all a TON of information, but I'm hoping that someone has some experience in moving from MVC2 to MVC3 and can give me a few pointers.

Thanks much.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I used MVC2, but IIRC the way client-side validation worked was totally different from MVC3.  For starters, you have to include the jquery-validate.js script in every view (or in a master page if you have that setup).

Comment: Thanks Erik.  So, I did figure out a few things.  Number one, I can use the old methods from MVC2 in MVC3.  Second, I didn't realize that the original authors of the code I'm updating had made modifications to the MicrosoftMvcValidation.js...  Once I added those modifications back in, most of it started to work.